# yii controller extends don't see model

Tags: php, oop, yii

I have GeneralController:

```
class GeneralController extends Controller
{
protected $model;

public function actionIndex($id=null) {
    $model = $model->findAll();
}

$this->render('index', array('model'=>$model)); 

}
```

I create new PostController with param

```
class PostController extends GeneralController {

    public function init()
    {
        $this->model = new Post;
    }
```

which extends from GeneralController.

When i call post/index $model is empty and write:

*Fatal error: Call to a member function findAll() on a non-object*

Comment: chalked out some code for you to take cue from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrong approach. Essence is to define the model variable as an accessible public type in the controller you are referencing.

```
class GeneralController extends Controller {

    public $model;

    public function init()
    {
        $this->model = new Post;
    }
```

next

```
class PostController extends GeneralController
{

public function actionIndex($id=null) {
    $model = $this->model->findAll();
}

$this->render('index', array('model'=>$model)); 

}
```

Tell us your results now.